# Validating Xml Documents via System.Xml.XmlReader and Generating Error Messages in German

Tags: c#, system.xml

We've got a project in which we do some XML schema validation. We're getting an Xml file as `Stream` at runtime, load it, find the corresponding `XSD` schema document and then process to parse it and log any validation errors we encountered like this:

```cs
var namespaceName = xDocument.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName;

var xmlReaderSettings = XmlReaderSettingsResolver.GetXmlReaderSettings(namespaceName, fileInformations);

xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) =>
{
    validationResult.Errors.Add(new CustomXmlSchemaError
    {
        // 'args.Message' is always in English, no matter which culture is set
        Message = args.Message,
        LineNumber = args.Exception.LineNumber,
        LinePosition = args.Exception.LinePosition
    });
};

using var xmlStreamCopy = new MemoryStream();
using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(xmlStreamCopy, Encoding.UTF8);
streamWriter.Write(fileAsString);
streamWriter.Flush();
xmlStreamCopy.Position = 0;
var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xmlStreamCopy, xmlReaderSettings);

// Read the whole file, the validation is done in the event handler while the file is being processed
while (xmlReader.Read()) { }
```

I would have expected to be able to get the error messages in German languages by setting the culture to German:

```cs
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de");
```

However, that doesn't seem to help. I've seen other .NET applications produce similar features in e.g. German, so I guess there's some way to use the correct resources, but I've been unable to find a way.

We're running this both on .NET Framework as well as on .NET / .NET Core, in Windows and Linux operating systems.

Comment: If you can’t get it to work, you could always call a web based translation API in Google or Microsoft that translates it for you. Overkill? Maybe! But if it’s what you want …!

Comment: Yeah, that's the brute force approach. I've also been thinking about manually translating this, but I'd rather use something built in, if it exists.

Comment: Yeah, of course.  Have you tried setting this one rather than the thread specific one?  I'm not close enough to know the differences but worth a shot ... `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` ...!  Actually, just read up on them, they're practically the same apart from the thread information so is unlikely to help.